# PSEXEC - Elevated Command prompt

Tags: sysinternals

Sorry if this has been asked a hundred times, I'm sure it might have been, but my searching skills don't seem to be finding the answer to my particular question today :(

I'm trying to execute a command on a server, from a domain user account, who has all the correct rights to perform the given action. I know this because if I login to the server under the admin account and then open the command prompt using 'Run as different User', specifying the login details of the domain user account, I can perform the relevant section of the below command successfully.

However, when I try running ("c:\NaviTest\psexec.exe" "\HOSTNAME" "c:\path to\server-command.exe" "arguments") from a command prompt on their host computer I get the 'Access Denied' message back.

If I launch the command prompt as administrator and change the syntax of the command as follows (where username is the logged in user and password is their password);

```
"c:\NaviTest\psexec.exe" -u username -p password "\\HOSTNAME" "c:\path to\server-command.exe" "arguments"
```

All works.

I know from this that its not running 'server-command.exe' the command that is causing the issue, its getting the connection to server using PSEXEC which seems to be failing unless the command prompt is being run in Elevated mode.

My question (as I haven't actually asked on yet!), is can PSEXEC work from the command prompt without having to be run administratively?

I'm trying to execute this as part of a much larger script, if I can't make it work without administrative privileges its not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this.......

https://serverfault.com/questions/280482/how-to-use-psexec-without-admin-privileges-on-target-machine

Basically, the user account executing the PSEXEC command needs local administrative rights on the destination host.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

This might cause due to prevailing issue.
psexcec will start a service(windows) in end point .
[check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
Run this as admin and will proceed without issues